# NODEJS readFile , writeFile and middlewares usage for error cases

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

1. I want to read file xx.txt
2. manipulate data and write to file yy.txt
3. all of this within a POST() that uses middleware that needs to update errors as well, and accordingly to transfer to next level so I can properly reply status and message.

I keep seeing that - if I use Async mode for read/write, the errors are not updated correctly on my req.output object (since it does not wait to see if there are errors), and if I try to use readFileSync, it gets stuck.
What am I missing?

```
    var middle_1 = function (req, res, next) {

        // setup my req.output to transfer data to the next middleware
        req.output = {
            statusCode : 200,
            message : `OK - 200`
        }

        fs.readFile(__dirname + `/xx.txt`, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                // update error for usage in next MIDDLEWARE
                req.output = {
                    statusCode : 401,
                    message : `Bad - 401`
                }
                return next(err);
            }

        //DO SOMETHING WITH the data        

        fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/yy.txt`, "DATA", 'utf8', function (err) {            
            // update error for usage in next MIDDLEWARE
            if (err) {
                req.output = {
                    statusCode : 409,
                    message : `Bad - 409`
                }
                return next(err);
            }
        });
    }); //end of readFile()

    next();
}

var middle_2 = function  (req, res, next) {

    // SOME THINGS DONE HERE

    next();

}


var response_end = function(req, res) {

    //setup my Status and Message response
    var status = req.output.statusCode;
    var message = req.output.message;

    res.status(status).send(message);
}


app.post('/' ,middle_1, middle_2, response_end )
```

Comment: You don't need the last `next();` in `middle_1`

Comment: BINGO! got it! now it works :-).
A small aftermath issue that now popped due to this solution -  I see the error message AND status (500 internal server error)  is OVERRIDING my res.status().json() response...

How can I take now this error in the response_end() and update my status and message accordingly so I won't expose internal errors outside of my server?

Comment: You should read up on how express error handlers work

Answer (score 0):

@blazesahlzen solution worked for me.
Thanks again for helping out :-).